# VXI-11 Protocol in iOS

Tags: ios, c, objective-c, swift

I've done some search on VXI-11 protocol library in iOS and couldn't get it.
Explored relevant RPC frameworks like gRPC, JSON RPC which doesn't support this type.

Do you have any suggestions on this?

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/applied-optics/vxi11 the first of many i can find, but its for unix. written in C this is not a big deal. And the original specification is still available [zip-file download from vxibus.org](http://www.vxibus.org/files/VXI_Specs/VXI-11.zip)

Comment: here a windows version for vxibus aka vxi-11 https://github.com/pocomane/winopenvxi and vxi-11 is using identical commands like SCPI to communicate with instruments.. so if you are able to read python here you go. https://github.com/SamThomas/PyExpLabSys/blob/master/SCPI.py